# BiometricPrompt: how to encrypt few strings?

Tags: android, kotlin, cryptography, aes, android-biometric-prompt

I need to encrypt few strings using biometric authentication in my application. I am using this code:

```
val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setSubtitle("subtitle")
        .setDescription("description")
        .setNegativeButtonText("button")
        .build()
val cryptoObject = BiometricPrompt.CryptoObject(getEncryptCipher())
val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(requireActivity(), Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
    override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
        val encodedString1 = Base64.encodeToString(result.cryptoObject?.cipher!!.doFinal(string1), Base64.DEFAULT)
        val encodedString2 = Base64.encodeToString(result.cryptoObject?.cipher!!.doFinal(string2), Base64.DEFAULT) // <- I got a crash in this line
        save(encodedString1, encodedString2)
    }
})
biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo, cryptoObject)


fun getEncryptCipher(): Cipher {
    var keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
    keyStore.load(null)
    if (!isKeyExists()) {
        createKey()
    }
    val key = keyStore.getKey("MyKeyAlias", null)
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance("${KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES}/${KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC}/${KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7}")
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key)
    return cipher
}

fun createKey() {
    val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES, PROVIDER_ANDROID_KEYSTORE)
    val builder = KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder("MyKeyAlias", KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
            .setBlockModes(KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC)
            .setEncryptionPaddings(KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7)
            .setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
    keyGenerator.init(builder.build())
    keyGenerator.generateKey()
}
```

First string encoded well. But when I am trying to encode second string I got a crash:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: IV has already been used. Reusing IV in encryption mode violates security best practices.
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreUnauthenticatedAESCipherSpi.addAlgorithmSpecificParametersToBegin(AndroidKeyStoreUnauthenticatedAESCipherSpi.java:244)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.ensureKeystoreOperationInitialized(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:237)
    at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:495)
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
    at com.me.myapp.MyFragment$MyMethod$biometricPrompt$1.onAuthenticationSucceeded(MyFragment.kt:49)
    at androidx.biometric.BiometricFragment$2$2.run(BiometricFragment.java:109)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

As I undestand I should use different IV for every string. But how to set new IV? I just receive an IV from BiometricPrompt.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the `init`? I tried looking up the documentation, but I guess Google doesn't believe in it. Note that `Cipher` (stupidly) has been described to reuse the IV in the documentation. What happens if you reissue the `BiometricPrompt`? Maybe it returns instantly?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `IvParameterSpec` parameter to `cipher.init`. Of course, that probably means that you have to refactor `getEncryptCipher` and call `cipher.init` afterwards

---

```
val encodedString2 = Base64.encodeToString(result.cryptoObject?.cipher!!.doFinal(string2), Base64.DEFAULT) // <- I got a crash in this line
```

You're trying to do too much in this line; it is both hard to read, and it won't make any difference to performance if you introduce a variable or two.

Comment: Sorry for bad readability, this is just a code for testing. IvParameterSpec is not applicable in this case. I can set it before BiometricPrompt will shown. And it works the same way - only for first string and on string2 I receive the same crash.